# How can I trigger a custom function in Ionic 2 tabs?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, navigation, ionic2

I'm trying to setup a custom page that instead of opening a new context on the application will be pushed on the navigation stack, so the user can return to where he/she was before opening the so called `CameraPage` like the following snippet on file **tabs.html**:

```
<ion-tabs>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="ios-paper"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="ios-calendar"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab (click)="openCamera()" tabIcon="custom-icon-plus"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabIcon="ios-trophy"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabIcon="ios-people"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And on the **tabs.ts** file I'm trying to receive this function in order to push the page on the navigation pile without just creating a new context, it's really important that the user returns to the spot he/she was before opening this particular page. Like the following snippet:

```
public openCamera() {
 console.log("clicked");
 this.navCtrl.push(CameraPage, {});
}
```

Unfortunately, the (click) event doens't get triggered when I tap on it, I've already tried creating a fake button that will float over the `<ion-tab>` element, but it gets ignored and doesn't appear on the built page... this is really frustrating, is there a way to trigger custom actions on the bottom navigation bar in Ionic 2?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: Sorry guys, the minute after I posted it I've found the solution, I just had to replace the `(click)` for `(ionSelect)` Output. :)

Comment: if you have found a solution please make an actual answer of it. and accept it. :)

Comment: Thanks @toskv, I'll do that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sorry guys, the minute after I posted it I've found the solution, I just had to replace the `(click)` for `(ionSelect)` Output. :)